# How does DHE-RSA work and why is PFS guaranteed?

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, certificates, man-in-the-middle, forward-secrecy

How does it work and why is forward secrecy guaranteed? I understood that it is not susceptible to a man-in-the-middle attack by using certificates in the beginning.

Comment: This might help you write in a better form. [What role does RSA play in DHE_RSA cipher suite?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55938/18298)

Comment: I suggest you avoid the confusing term ‘forward secrecy’ and instead [focus on when keys are erased](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75025).